# How to disable Teredo Tuneling Pseudo Interface in my Windows 7?

Tags: windows

This program randomly exists on my computer. I found it while browsing around in my computer's control panel. How do I remove or disable it?

Answer (score 1):

finally found the procedure after finding a lot,

check this url : [Solution](https://livefortech.net/teredo-tunneling-pseudo-interface/)

Type CMD in the windows start menu, right-click on it and Run as Administrator.
There, type-

```
netsh interface teredo set state disabled
```

Now go to Device Manager and expand the Network Adapter option.
You will find the Tunneling Pseudo-Interface and uninstall it.

Open the CMD and type in the commands we mentioned above once again similarly.

Open Device Manager and click on Scan for the new hardware changes.